# Combine equivalent of RxJS iif

Tags: swift, combine

[iif](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif) is a useful operator that can decide which Observable to subscribe to at runtime. Is there an equivalent in Swift Combine framework with publisher? If not, what's a good workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a direct equivalent, but you can use a `Deferred` publisher:

```
let p1: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> = ...
let p2: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> = ...

let condition = Bool.random()

let iif = Deferred { condition ? p1 : p2 }
```